# String to array of Integers php

Tags: php, arrays, string, integer

I wan to convert a string for example 1,2,3,4,5,6 to an array of integers in php?
I find functions that only have access to the first character of the string for example 1.
How can I conert the whole string to array?

```
function read_id_txt()
{

        $handle_file = fopen("temporalfile.txt", 'r'); 

        $i=0;

        while ($array_var[$i] = fgets($handle_file, 4096)) { 
            echo "<br>";
            print_r($array_var[i]);
            $i++;
        }

        fclose($handle_file);   

        $temp=explode(" ", $array_var[0]);      

        return $temp;   


}
```

Comment: in the txt i ve these values: 1,2,4,56,6,1,23,34,54,75,43

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use PHP's [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
$arr = explode("," $str); // array( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' );

foreach ($arr AS $index => $value)
    $arr[$index] = (int)$value; 

// casts each value to integer type -- array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 );
```

As suggested by [Tim Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142162/tim-cooper), using [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) is simpler than the above loop:

```
array_walk($arr, 'intval');
```

Comment: OK what i ve done is the above 
$handle_file = fopen("temporalfile.txt", 'r');
$i=0;
while ($array_var[$i] = fgets($handle_file, 4096)) { 
$i++;}
fclose($handle_file);
$temp=explode(" ", $array_var[0]);
print_r($arr);

it returns Array ( [0] => 1,2,4,56,6,1,23,34,54,75,43 )
i want to have every value in different cell of the matrix.

Comment: @Josh:  That's an array of strings, not integers.

Comment: @Josh:  You can simplify that loop with a simple call to `array_walk`:  `$arr = array_walk('intval', $arr);`.

Comment: @Tim Good call! I didn't think of `intval` (doh!), and thought the loop would be simpler than `array_walk` because of the necessary function definition.

Comment: Xm my prob was in exmplode i put the space character instead of ','. With , it works. Thank tou for your time guys.

Comment: The array_walk thing didn't work for me with php 5.4, but array_map did: $arr = array_map('intval', $arr);

Comment: @Riesling Keep in mind, `array_map` will return a an array, whereas `array_walk` returns a boolean and modifies the original array. Both should work.

Comment: This will return non-numeric values as well because of the use of intval.  "" == 0 using intval

Comment: Beware! This wont work i PHP 5.3+! use `$arr = array_map('intval', $arr);` instead.

Comment: No @Josh, `array_walk()` does NOT modify the original array by default.  https://3v4l.org/qU4Qo  You have to explicitly tell it to modify the elements.  This answer is misleading researchers.

Answer (score 11):

```
return array_map('intval', explode(",", '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'));
```

Comment: array_walk returns a bool. This was the only way I could get my string to convert to an array of int to use in Jpgraph.

Comment: array_walk makes the modification on the first parameter, so in @josh solution, the $arr variable will contain the integer array not the return value.

Answer (score 4):

**The above answers could potentially return non-numeric values**

#### array_walk & array_map with intval

Both return arrays that are tainted with non-numeric values.

```php
$string = ',g,6,4,3,f,32,a,';
$array = explode(',', $string);
array_walk($array, 'intval');
$arrayMap = array_map('intval', $array);
var_dump($array);
var_dump($arrayMap);
/*
     array(9) {
      [0]=>
      string(0) ""
      [1]=>
      string(1) "g"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "6"
      [3]=>
      string(1) "4"
      [4]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [5]=>
      string(1) "f"
      [6]=>
      string(2) "32"
      [7]=>
      string(1) "a"
      [8]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
 */
```

#### array_filter to only return numeric values

```php
$string = ',g,6,4,3,f,32,a,';
$array = explode(',', $string);
$numericOnlyArray = array_filter($array,'is_numeric');

var_dump($numericOnlyArray);

/*
    result:
    array(4) {
      [2]=>
      string(1) "6"
      [3]=>
      string(1) "4"
      [4]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [6]=>
      string(2) "32"
    }
*/
```

#### To get only integers

```php
$string = ',g,6,4,3,f,32,a,';
$array = explode(',', $string);
$result = array_map('intval', array_filter($array, 'is_numeric'));

var_dump($result);

/*
    result:
    array(4) {
      [2]=>
      int(6)
      [3]=>
      int(4)
      [4]=>
      int(3)
      [6]=>
      int(32)
    }
    }
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

```
explode(",",'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score -3):

You can use http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.