# Remove zeros that follow a 1 in an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am getting the values of an array of checkboxes (created dynamically). There were several issues, but I narrowed it to a certain point. Now the abstract of the problem is this (forget for a second these are checkboxes and just imagine we are working with an array of numbers).

I have an array **store[20]** which contains values of 0s or 1s.
I need to get rid of every 0 that follows a one.
Ex. lets assume my array is **store={0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}**.
I need to create a new array that will be like this **check={0, 1, 1, 0}**.
The third and fifth terms dont have to be inserted in the new array because they follow the second and fourth term (which are ones).

Also, in case you wonder, there are no occurrences of two consecutive ones, so no need to worry about that.

Here is my php code (but implementations in other languages are the same since its just for loops and arrays):

```
$j=0;   $count=0;
    for($j=0;$j<20; $j++) {
        $check[$j] = $store[$j + $count];
        if($store[$j]) {
            $count = $count + 1;                
        }
    }
```

The code is not working correctly. Maybe I am dead wrong in the way im implementing it. But Im a bit tired and started seeing things. I really can't see what im doing wrong.

PS: I didnt include the array declarations and other preceding code because i already tested it and I know they are ok. The problem is in the logic of this part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** 8 years of experience later, I would simply use a `foreach` loop on the elements and checking the previous value in the array when you reach a `0`. If it's `1`, then don't include it in the new array.

```
$store = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0];
$check = [];
foreach ($store as $index => $value) {
    if ($index > 0 && $value === 0 && $store[$index - 1] === 1) {
        continue;
    }
    $check[] = $value;
}
var_dump($check);
```

This avoids the overhead of converting the values to a string then doing replacements on it before converting it back, it simply creates a new array with the desired elements.

The original answer is preserved below, but I no longer recommend it.

---

In PHP you could just use `str_split`, a little regex and an `implode` without having to worry about a for loop. Adding in `array_map`, the results will be returned as integers instead of strings.

```
$check = array_map('intval',str_split(preg_replace('/10/','1',implode('',$store))));
```

Demo:

```
<?php
    $store = array(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    $check = str_split(preg_replace('/10/', '1', implode('', $store)));
    var_dump($check);
    $check = array_map('intval', $check);
    var_dump($check);
?>
```

Comment: Actually, I like your elegant solution, but the datatype is a little of a big deal in this case (as I mentioned in the beginning of the question, this is just an abstraction of the real problem. I cannot even test the solution if its not in integer result) But I will see if I can convert the result and let all know

Comment: The above solution works perfectly and its very easy to do the converting. For that, check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963910/string-to-array-of-integers-php The accepted answer was the best way to convert between datatypes.

Comment: @amygrimaldi I added the conversion to the answer.

Comment: I already checked myself came up with the same method (cant expect other people to do all the work for me). Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Why is the is there one pattern which checks for `01` and another pattern that checks for `10`?  Rather confusing.  Furthmore `preg_replace()` is unnecessary overkill for a literal replacement task -- `str_replace()` or `strtr()` will suffice.  If you really wanted to shoehorn a `preg_` call into this task, `preg_split()` can combine the replace & split subtasks. https://3v4l.org/tVHXe  Comparing this answer against the others, though, it doesn't look to have superior elegance and is certainly doing more cycles.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you for the notes, I corrected the error in the original answer and added a simpler solution with my recommended approach as of today. I would urge you to consider positing your solutions as answer as well, especially to avoid "link rot" (external links can become unreachable in the future)

Comment: I won't be posting a new answer because I believe the most simple, elegant, and performant solution is already posted by VolkerK

Answer (score 1):

As I understood the question you just need the preceeding element to decide whether a 0 is included in the result or not:

```
$store = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0];   
$prev = 0;
$result = [];
foreach ($store as $e) {
    if ($e || !$prev) {
        $result[] = $e;
    }
    $prev = $e;
}
var_export($result);
```

This approach generates the desired output in a single iteration of the input array.

```
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 1,
  3 => 0,
)
```

Comment: The functional-style equivalent is https://3v4l.org/IcO40

Answer (score 0):

This is the output I get from running your code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [4] =>
    [5] =>
    [6] =>
    [7] =>
    [8] =>
    [9] =>
    [10] =>
    [11] =>
    [12] =>
    [13] =>
    [14] =>
    [15] =>
    [16] =>
    [17] =>
    [18] =>
    [19] =>
)
```

So basically it's working, except for the presence of null values at the end of your array since you're reading values outside of the bounds of the `$store` array. Simply check whether you're outside of the bounds of the array in your for loop. Notice I added `+$count` to the operation.

```
$store = array(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
$j=0;
$count=0;
$check = array();

for($j=0;$j+$count<count($store); $j++) {
    $check[] = $store[$j + $count];
    if($store[$j+$count]) {
        $count = $count + 1;                
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 0
)
```

Comment: Null values at the end of the array are not an issue, I am not going to read them later anyway so dont mind them. And it did (by coincidence) work with the above input. It does work with some inputs and not with others. For example try $store = array(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 );