# Converting several array values to integer

Tags: php, string, integer

As shown in [String to array of Integers php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963910/string-to-array-of-integers-php), there is a solution to convert ALL array elements to integer. But what if my array looks like this:

```
$v=array(0.00, "0.00", "test", 50);
```

I need a converted array where all numeric elements (even if quoted, like "0.00") are converted to integer, but strings (like "test") must remain strings...

Answer (score 1):

Try with `array_map`. It will convert all the elements(except the strings you mentioned) to integer.

```
function convert_data($data) {
    if (is_numeric($data)) {
        $data = (int) $data;
    }
    return $data;
}
$ints[] = array_map('convert_data', $v);
var_dump($ints);
```