# Converting array of string to array of integers in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I followed the leads in the questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963910/string-to-array-of-integers-php) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593765/how-to-convert-array-values-from-string-to-int).

I am trying to convert an input stream of numbers to an array of integers. The code should be self explanatory.

```
$handle = fopen("php://stdin","r");

print("Enter space separated numbers to be made to an array\n");

$numStream = fgets($handle);

print("Creating array from : {$numStream}\n");

//Using explode to create arrays
//now we have an array of Strings
$numArray = explode(" ", $numStream);

var_dump($numArray);

print(getType($numArray[0]));
print("\n");
array_walk($numArray, 'intval');
print(getType($numArray[1]));
print("\n");
var_dump($numArray);
print_r($numArray);
```

I am trying to convert the String array,

```
array_walk($numArray, 'intval')
```

The last two print blocks prints the type of an array element before and after conversion.

The output is string in both the cases

```
string
string
```

I wonder what is going on here? Possibly..

1. The conversion is wrong
2. How the type is checked is wrong

Or possibly both.

Adding the complete input and output,

```
$ php arrays/arrayStringToInteger.php 
Enter space separated numbers to be made to an array
1 1
Creating array from : 1 1

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1

)
string
string
/home/ubuntu/workspace/basics/arrays/arrayStringToInteger.php:22:
 array(2) {
   [0] =>
    string(1) "1"
   [1] =>
    string(2) "1
 "
}
 Array
 (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1

)
```

Comment: can you show the output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($numArray);`? show us

Comment: @Anant added a few more input statements and their outputs

Comment: you have already accepted answer. So if you have any problem ask a new question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should use `array_map` instead of `array_walk`:

```
$numArray = array_map('intval', $numArray);
```

If you still want to use `array_walk` - refer to a [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php#refsect1-function.array-walk-parameters) which says:

> If callback needs to be working with the actual values of the array, specify the first parameter of callback as a reference. Then, any changes made to those elements will be made in the original array itself.

As `intval` function doesn't work with references you need to wrap it in some other logics, something like:

```
array_walk($numArray, function(&$v){ $v = intval($v); });
// which is the same as @BizzyBob solution)))
```

Answer (score 2):

`intval()` does not set the value, it only returns the value.

You could do this:

```
array_walk($numArray, function(&$x){$x = intval($x);});
```