# Convert implode string to interger variable PHP

Tags: php, integer, var-dump

Suppose after applying implode to an array , I got a String for example :-

$var = 1631075,1631076;

On applying var_dump to $var , I received the output as string(15) "1631075,1631076"

how will I convert entire $var into Integer variable . Such that the var_dump display int(15)1631075,1631076

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid integer. Do you want to get the integer `16310751631076`?

Comment: I dont understand your question, do you want to create an array of integer?

Comment: No actually I want to get an integer as :-

1631075,1631076

Comment: A valid integer will not include and commas only numbers. You format the integer->string to show commas for easy readability later. Strip out any non-numbers and do $var = intval($string_with_only_numbers);

Comment: Plus, that comma is not in the correct place as a thousands separator.

Comment: I tired applying intval(1631075,1631076) but it only worked on 1st argument i.e 

int(10)1631075 ; and the 2nd agrument along with comma was left unchanged

Comment: Do you want 2 integers?

Comment: Yes 2 integers separated by a comma

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = '1631075,1631076';
foreach(explode(',',$var) as $val){
 echo intval($val);
}
```

or something like

```
$var = '1631075,1631076';
$integers = explode(',',$var);
$converted = array_map('intval', $integers);
```

Comment: But Sir ,it is giving the output as 16310751631076;
how can I get 1631075,1631076 as integer

Comment: "1631075,1631076" is not an integer and can't be. That can only be a string if you want that inside one variable.

Comment: Sir actually I want the final output as [1631075,1631076] (integer format)
the required array is Array ( [0] => 1631075 [1] => 1631076 )

Comment: Use "intval()" on the array values before handling mathematical functions. Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963910/string-to-array-of-integers-php